# What is the advantage of using Formidable over basic php?

Tags: wordpress

I'm currently using formidable in my project as suggested by my supervisor. I think that using formidable is quite restricted and less flexible. Maybe there is a better way to fully utilize it over php

Comment: With Formidable Form Pro you could do what you want. I have always find a way to do what I want. It faster, easier, and you have a very good security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is more useful for rapid prototyping. Besides, you can still tweak the php code manually, if you want